# How to step into .Net assembly in VS2010 with source folder specified?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, assemblies

I have thirdparty .NET assembly.

How to step into sources of this assembly in VS2010?

I specified the path to sources in "Solution Properties \ Common Properties \ Debug Source Files". But this does not help.

Comment: That is the correct setting.  Do you have the .pdb file for this assembly?  Can you open a source code file by hand and set a breakpoint?

Comment: It seems that I have not specified .pdb, investigating now

Comment: Don't specify it, just copy it in the same directory as the DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below link shows the steps to step into .Net assembly.

since you specified the source then probably you may need just to check the last 3 steps

[MS BLOG](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/07/12/step-into-net-framework-4-0-source-code.aspx)